# How does the ExtJS4 Column class work?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I wrote my own sub-class, for some selection stuff and paging etc. But those all worked with the `renderer()`, which required them to return a string.

This worked fine, I created some image-tags and returned those.

But how does this class work in detail?
I want a sub-class which displays a chart in a cell, which should technically be no problem, but the `renderer()` doesn't seem the right place for it, since it only works for strings.

Does the Class get instantiated for every row? or is it really just one instance for a column, which methods get called for every row with the needed data and the instances don't hold any state about the rows?

Answer (score 1):

The `renderer()` mechanism is actually implemented in `Ext.grid.column.Column`, for which there is one per column.

As you have mentioned, the `renderer()` function returns a string, which could be an HTML string (which could be rather complex - have a look at the templates used by ExtJs for the standard columns). But you cannot return a component (chart).

To the best of my knowledge (based on my own understanding and replies to similar questions), ExtJs does not offer a straight-forward way to render components within grid cells. If you really think about it - you are asking a grid for much more than its intended role. It was designed to present records per raw, with the addition of simple user interaction facilities, like checkboxes.

But what you are really asking for is more of a way to layout charts, for which problem i suggest you look into the [Table layout](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table).

Alternatively you should be able to render a chart into a dom element, which will be defined in your own custom column template. But I will consider this to be an involved task.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer :) I want to render sparklines in grids, that's why I thought about writing my own column subclass. But after I debugged through the whole code it seems like you're right, I have to output a DOM-element with a generated ID and let my generated chart rendered into this element, to get flex-sizing will probably an issue :\